# Adding buttons below JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I am trying to add two buttons below the `JTextArea` using the Eclipse WindowBuilder, but I can't. I tried to change the layout, but I couldn't find a way to add buttons where I want and to re-size the `JTextArea` in an easy way.

```
public TestScrollPane03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(100, 50);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

How would I go about adding buttons below my original `textArea`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have two panels, one for your `textArea`, and one for your input (in this case buttons).  I think something like this is what you are looking for:

[image]

```
public class Test
{
    public static void createFrame()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                panel.setOpaque(true);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setFont(Font.getFont(Font.SANS_SERIF));
                JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
                inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
                JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
                DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
                caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
                panel.add(scroller);
                inputpanel.add(input);
                inputpanel.add(button);
                panel.add(inputpanel);
                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                input.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        createFrame();
    }
}
```

If you want your frame to look more like those of the OS you are running on, you can add `.setLookAndFeel()` before you make the `frame` visible:

```
try 
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What adding the `UIManager` looks like (notably a bit smaller):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. can you please show me the steps of doing this on the builder? ( i mean setting the layouts..)

Comment: I didn't use the a builder to do this, so I don't know how. I learned how to do this by only using code and lots of testing.